# pyqt: QTextEdit: save changed text

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtextedit

I am trying to call my function with changed text as parameter.

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(Ui().textEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL("textChanged()"), lambda mytext = Ui().textProfileDesc.toHtml(): self.myprint(mytext))
```

But it doesn't work, in mytext is the text before change.

```
def myprint(self, mytext):
    print "text1",mytext
    print "text2", Ui().textEdit.toHtml()
```

text1 - text before change, why??

text2 - changed text as expected

Answer (score 1):

You connect the signal to `textEdit` but query the text from `textProfileDesc`.

Also, I think you don't really need lambda:

```
Ui().textEdit.textChanged.connect(self.myprint)
```